# If $\mu$ is a complex measure and $\|\mu\| = \mu(X)$, then $\mu$ is a positive measure

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, complex-integration

Taken from Conway's A course in functional analysis Chapter 3 Section 7 Problem 2

Problem Statement: Let $X$ be a set and $\Omega$ a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $X$. Suppose $\mu$ is a complex-valued countably additive measure defined on $\Omega$ such that $\|\mu\| = \mu(X) < \infty$. Show that $\mu(\Delta) \geq 0$ for every $\Delta$ in $\Omega$

Given the section this problem is in, I assume we are supposed to use Banach limits to solve this problem. However, Banach limits are linear functionals acting on $l^\infty$ spaces which makes it hard for me to see how to apply it to this problem.

Comment: You should first read the definition of  a complex measure. It does not say $\mu (\Delta) \geq 0$.

Answer (score 3):

According to a consequence of Radon-Nikodym Theorem (see Rudin, Real & Complex Analysis, Theorem 6.12), there exists a measurable function $h:X\to \mathbb C$, with $|h(x)|=1$, for all $x\in X$, such that
$$
d\mu=h\,d|\mu|,
$$
and hence
$$
\int_X d|\mu|=\|\mu\|=\mu(X)=\int_X d\mu=\int_X d\mu=\int_X h\, d|\mu|
$$
Hence
$$
0=\int_X (1-h)\, d|\mu|=\int_X (1-\mathrm{Re}\,h)\, d|\mu|,
$$
and hence Re$\,h(x)=1$, almost everywhere, which implies that Im$\,h(x)=0$, almost everywhere, since $|h|=1$. Thus $h(x)=1$, almost everywhere, and hence $\mu$ is a positive measure.